# Representing a website in a BPMN 2.0 diagram

Tags: bpmn

Is there a specific icon to represent a website in a BPMN 2.0 diagram?

For a particular case I've been given, the user in the system posts a document to a website, and I'm not sure how exactly to represent this.

Apologies if this is on the wrong Stack Exchange site - I've posted it here as there's been previous BPMN posts to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *specific* element for modeling a website in BPMN 2.0.
However there is the *generic* Data Object element, see [the BPMN 2.0 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF), page 30 (60 in PDF), respectively 205 (235 in PDF):

> Data Objects provide information about what
>   Activities require to be performed and/or what they
>   produce [...]

In some cases, one might want to regard websites as actors within a process and model them using a dedicated pool/lane.

A third option some BPMN modeling tools provide, are custom BPMN elements (BPMN 2.0 is extensible), e.g. the element *IT System*, as existent in [Signavio's](http://www.signavio.com/) modeling tool.

In your case, you could e.g. only model the website as a Data Object and link it as an output to the *post document task*. This would make sense if the document posted to the website is created as part of this task.
In case the posted document is already existent, you could link it as an input to the task:

[image: BPMN Examples]

Answer (score 5):

You may model the website as a participant, like an [NPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-player_character). Then, you can model additional activities of the website, for example, how the website processes the posted document, whom does it notifies, where it stores results, and so on.

Take a look at my paper: [From a BPMN Black Box to a Smalldb State Machine](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8698227) — The paper describes an algorithm to infer the implementation of a given NPC participant automatically, but before that, it shows how to draw such business processes in a useful way.

Pizza order & delivery example from the paper (the middle participant is a web application):
[image: Pizza example]